# how the -ss command works internally

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like to understand how a command like this

`ffmpeg -ss 100 -i input.avi -t 10 -c copy -y output.mp4`

works inside.

In particular, I am interested in how the -ss operation is performed here. I know it seeks the closest keyframe before 100, but how exactly does it find that closest keyframe?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FFmpeg analyzes each input and generates an index per-stream. Most formats store only keyframes in this index. When an input seek is carried out, ffmpeg looks up the nearest index entry which is smaller than the seek point and emits packets from there.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I am interested in how the index is generated and how the search is performed on it, as well as which formats store not only keyframes in the index. Could you tell me where I can read about these things?

Comment: As the demuxer reads parses packet headers or packet data in the header, it adds the entries to the index. Your best bet is to study the source.

Comment: I agree that studying source is the best way to understand how everything works. It's just that there are quite many files in the ffmpeg source code, and I don't even approximately know which of them I need to pay attention to.